# Expose Multibinding through a component dependency

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I am currently working on a multi module app.
There are basically 4 modules :

- The app module with the UI
- The contracts module with the models/interfaces
- The implementation modules with actual business logic
- The dependency injection module, which allows the app to be provided with the implementations

This means the application does not depend directly on the implementations module.

I have basically the following setup :

The application component

```
@Component(
        dependencies = {
                BaseComponent.class
        },
        modules = {
                AndroidInjectionModule.class,
                AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
                ContributesAndroidInjectorModule.class
        }
)
@ApplicationScope
public interface ApplicationComponent extends AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        Builder baseComponent(BaseComponent baseComponent);

        ApplicationComponent build();
    }
}
```

The base component

```
@Component(
        modules = {
                ...
        }
)
@Singleton
public interface BaseComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder context(@ApplicationContext Context context);

        @BindsInstance
        Builder configuration(AppConfiguration configuration);

        BaseComponent build();
    }

    ExposedDependency exposedDependency();
}
```

This setup works perfectly, except with modules using @ContributesAndroidInjector installed in the BaseComponent : I do not find a way to have the map containing the AndroidInjector exposed on the BaseComponent and added to the ApplicationComponent.

Is there a way to expose some sort of map in the BaseComponent to add AndroidInjectors to the ApplicationComponent ?

(I'll try to extract this problem to a git repo without sensitive information)

Answer (score 0):

Not a straight answer, but I ended up making abstract activities/fragments/services in my business logic module, and concrete classes in the DI module.

The concrete classes get a component from the application and use it to inject dependencies.

Pretty much the old Dagger ways from before AndroidInjector...